# Howto handle moving Items in OSMDroid maps

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am trying to use osmdroid to display a map with items. Looking at the API's of ItemizedOverlay (and derived) and OverlayItem I can not see a way to modify items (change position and marker) once they are created. 
OverlayItem has functions to change the marker but not the position. 
As my items are going to change position rather often I wonder if:

- osmdroid has a better API hidden away somewhere
- I have to replace the overlay every time one of its items position changes.
- I can mess around with the list of Items replacing items
- something else I haven't thought of.

PS: Digging some more I discovered that extending ItemizedOverlay would be the way. This way I can mess around with the items, but I still have to call populate() every time I change a coordinate and thus discard the internal list...

Answer (score 0):

That's one reason why ItemizedOverlay and derived are hated, and the [Marker](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0#0-using-the-marker-overlay) has been added to osmdroid, as simple and flexible as its Google Maps API equivalent.